# Inserting data to the table by querying from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I want to populate the table 'Employee' by querying data from 'Access' and 'Employee_old' tables.

I want to, only populate newer records that are not present in the 'Employee' table.

Below query works fine but I don't know how to populate 'AccessType'[using AccessID] from 'Account' table
Any help is appreciated

```
INSERT INTO Employee (Name,Dept, Location, AccessID )
SELECT Name, Dept, Location, AccessID
from Employee_old
WHERE TimeStamp > (
    SELECT TimeStamp
    FROM Employee
    ORDER BY TIME_CREATED DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)
```

```
Table Account
-- AccountID [PK]
-- AccessID
-- AccessType

Table Employee
-- EmployeeID [PK]
-- Name
-- Dept
-- Location
-- AccessID
-- AccessType

Table Employee_old
-- EmployeeID [PK]
-- Name
-- Dept
-- Location
-- AccessID
-- ManagerID
-- Grade
```

Comment: Why are you repeated `AccessType` in the `Employee` table?  Your data model is broken.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this is just a sample example. Real tables are much more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, you have to join on table `account` using `AccessID`.

```
INSERT INTO Employee (Name,Dept, Location, AccessID, AccessType)
SELECT 
  Name,
  Dept, 
  Location, 
  AccessID,
  AccessType 
from Employee_old eo
join account a
on eo.accessId = a.accessId
WHERE TimeStamp > (SELECT TimeStamp FROM Employee ORDER BY TIME_CREATED DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
```